# Google Cloud Bucket: Download a directory using a signed URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I'm currently serving individual files via an API using a signed URL as defined in this official guide:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#python-sample

Is there a way to create a signed URL to download an entire **directory**?

Ideally I'd like to avoid having my server to download each individual file and prepare it as a single download, so if there is a way to do this on the GCP side, it would be much easier

Comment: Easy answer: Folders do not exist! So you can't. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects#simulated-folders If you want to perform bulk download, create a TAR with the file that you want, put it in Cloud Storage, and generate a single signed URL on it. No other option to avoid multiple file download

Comment: From the above comment, I believe that your issue is solved. Can you post your answer as a solution? So that, it will be useful for others who are facing same issue

Comment: If you deploy Cloud CDN, you can use prefix wildcards. Prefixes are Google's method of simulating folders (directory trees). [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#programmatically_create_signed_urls_with_a_url_prefix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy answer: Folders do not exist! So you can't. More detail here on the [folder management in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects#simulated-folders)

If you want to perform bulk download, create a TAR with the file that you want, put it in Cloud Storage, and generate a single signed URL on it. No other option to avoid multiple file download (and multiple signedURL generation)

Comment: Google Cloud CDN supports `Signed URL Prefixes` [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#programmatically_create_signed_urls_with_a_url_prefix) ***Prefixes allow access to any URL with the same prefix***

Comment: That's correct. I was focused only on GCS service, but using another one could nicely help and solve the issue. Thanks @JohnHanley

Comment: Your answer is correct for the question asked. Just another idea.